# Having trouble getting poclbm to work on linux, Segmentation fault

Tags: linux, poclbm

I am a linux noob, so please take that in to account.  I believe i have compile poclbm and all it's dependencies correctly however when I try and run it

```
python poclbm.py http://xxxx@xxxxx@pit.deepbit.net:8332 -d 0
```

I get the following error

```
21/02/2014 15:45:26, Setting server (xxxx@xxxxx @ pit.deepbit.net:8332)
pit.deepbit.net:8332 21/02/2014 15:45:26, checking for stratum...               
Segmentation fault
```

Does anyone have an idea of why this might be happening?  Changing my logging a bit I can see it's a `3044 Segmentation fault`.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

This turned out to be a problem with installing two different versions of the nvidia driver on *nix